# Shared mutable object in Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class like this. (My actual class is different. I am using this to explain the problem).  This class instance is shared between 2 threads.

However those 2 threads (`thread1` and `thread2`), call the methods `addToList1` and `addToList2` respectively. We can safely assume that `thread1` does not call `addToList2` vice versa.

My question is - Can I still have race condition in this case?

```
class Dummy {

   private List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList();
   private List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList();
   
   public void addToList1(Integer a) { list1.add(a); }
   public void addToList2(Integer a) { list2.add(a); }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is <sup>probably</sup> no issue since the two threads don't modify the same object.

The threads do not modify the instances of the `Dummy` class. From the outside behaviour of the class, it does look like this `Dummy` instance is being modified concurrently. But looking at the implementation, it is clear that the modifications are merely forwarded to different objects – the separate `ArrayList` instances.

So instead of concurrent modifications of the same object

```
                      +---------+
thread1 ------------> |         |
         addToList1   |  Dummy  |
                      |         |
thread2 ------------> |         |
         addToList2   +---------+
```

we actually have concurrent modifications of separate objects

```
                      +---------+         +-------+
thread1 --------------|---------|-------> | list1 |
         addToList1   |  Dummy  |  add    +-------+
                      |         |         +-------+
thread2 --------------|---------|-------> | list2 |
         addToList2   +---------+  add    +-------+
```

Even if we were modifying the contents of the same object, this may or may not be fine depending on the modifications. The Java Virtual Machine provides comparatively strong guarantees about which operations are atomic. For example, assigning a variable (including fields of an object) is always atomic. In contrast, the `ArrayList#add()` method is not threadsafe so that it must not be called from multiple threads on the same object concurrently.

I've qualified my statement in the leading paragraph with a “probably” because what qualifies as a race condition depends on the context. In this answer, I'm mainly concerned about the JVM memory model. But, it could be that your application expects `list1` and `list2` only to change in a particular pattern or order. For example, a third thread might have the expectation that the two lists always have the same length. Then, your current design would fail to achieve that constraint. There would be a race condition in that thread3 might start reading the ArrayLists before thread1 or thread2 have finished adding their item to the list. This would require you to implement some explicit synchronization, for example using a Semaphore so that either thread1 & thread2 can access the data, or thread3.

Comment: Great answer which addresses the main point and a few corner cases.